# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_utimensat", referenced from: _cazW_info in libHSdirectory-1.3.3.0.a(Posix.o)

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

I'm trying to install haskell-ide-engine. Below are the commands

```
git clone https://github.com/haskell/haskell-ide-engine --recursive
cd haskell-ide-engine 
./install.hs build-all
```

The last command `./install.hs build-all` failed with the below error -

```
    [146 of 150] Compiling Distribution.Client.Sandbox ( Distribution/Client/Sandbox.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Sandbox.o )
    [147 of 150] Compiling Distribution.Client.Reconfigure ( Distribution/Client/Reconfigure.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Reconfigure.o )
    [148 of 150] Compiling Distribution.Client.Exec ( Distribution/Client/Exec.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/Exec.o )
    [149 of 150] Compiling Distribution.Client.CmdLegacy ( Distribution/Client/CmdLegacy.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Distribution/Client/CmdLegacy.o )
    [150 of 150] Compiling Main             ( main/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/cabal/cabal-tmp/Main.o )
    Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/cabal/cabal ...
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_utimensat", referenced from:
          _cazW_info in libHSdirectory-1.3.3.0.a(Posix.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    `gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
)
```

my mac os Sierra version 10.12.6.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `utimensat` is available in Mac OS 10.13 and later.

Comment: @BobDalgleish - do you have any idea how to install utimensat in older mac versions? `brew install utimensat` is giving error `No available formula with the name "utimensat"`

Comment: It is an operating system call. It can't be "installed". If you are unable to install MacOS 10.13 or later, you might consider spinning up a virtual machine running linux. Alternatively, you can try to install an older version of the haskell-ide-engine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the culprit is that the Unix package is built with `ghc` on a newer macOS version. Try using your own build of the Unix package.